# Javascript - EPERM: operation not permitted, open '.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-27492'

Tags: javascript

I am calling an api thousands of times over and over to retrieve json data. On completely random occasions, my code, that is in a loop, fails. I get the following Error:

EPERM: operation not permitted, open '.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-27492'

The error message states that it is an "error because the operation is not permitted", yet i can't seem to work out why this is the case, as i run into this error randomly within a loop. The loop works fine 999/1000 times, but just on the one random occasion it cant seem to read the file and crashes the program. Anyone have any idea what's gone wrong?

Extra details you might need

Windows 10 64bit |
Running with node |
Synchronous mode not Async.

If you need any more details just tell me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no solutions to the answer, a few possible ways i have found to get past this:

1. Advanced Error Handling
2. Collect the data in batches
3. Just process more data per request and thus cut down on the chance that the request solution breaks.